# Variable value does not redirect to another frame

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

When my variable reaches the number 94, i am not redirected to the frame "two". Any suggestions?

```
import flash.events.Event;

stop();

//addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,cakeShow);

var cakeSize:Number = 100;

cakeButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,decCake);

function decCake(event:MouseEvent):void {

    cakeSize--;
    cake.text = String (cakeSize);

}

cake.text = String(cakeSize);

if (cakeSize==94) {

gotoAndStop("two");

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only check your variable once, you should do it every time something happens. So, you have to update your function.

```
function decCake(event:MouseEvent):void {
    cakeSize--;
    cake.text = String (cakeSize);
    if (cakeSize==94) {
        gotoAndStop("two");
    }
}
```

Update: Seeing you need to constantly monitor a variable, you need to declare it as a property.

```
private var _cakeSize:int;
public function get cakeSize():int {return _cakeSize;}
public function set cakeSize(value:int):void {
    _cakeSize=value;
    if (_cakeSize==94) {
        gotoAndStop("two");
    }
}
```

This way a "set" function (aka "setter") is called every time you need to set a value to a variable, and "get" function (aka "getter") is called every time you check its value. So you let that `cakeSize--;` remain in place, but in reality Flash will first call getter, take its returned value, decrement it and call setter with the new value. Note, you will have to provide special behavior for the setter function should you need to go to frame "two" once or under certain conditions and not every time cakeSize is assigned the value 94.

Comment: This function is appended to button click.
What if button is not avaliable after some time, so i cannot append variable check to it? Is there some kind of listener which checks when number reaches the 94?

Comment: Yes, but you have to make a setter property for the said number. It is a function, so it will called every time when a new value is assigned to the variable. Make it like so: (see updated answer)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for a [timer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html), in case you don't have one running already.

```
var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000,0);

timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,update,false,0,true);

timer.start();

function update(e) {

      if (cakeSize==94) { timer=null; gotoAndStop("two");}
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to remove the listener in update() if the condition is met, otherwise the other gotoAndStop() commands issued from elsewhere won't behave as intended while cakeSize remains at 94 :)

Comment: It's a weak event listener & the timer is set to null... so the listener should be handled by the gc...

Comment: Oops, didn't notice that weak reference is used. Sorry. (I always use strong references)